# php date issue, sometimes 1 becomes a zero

Tags: php

long time reader, first post.

We have an open issues list on our website, issues go past due automatically when the due date is reached. The code used to work fine but started behaving illogically recently and its frying my brain trying to figure out why.

The website is hosted on wordpress but I believe the problem is a basic PHP issue.

Its a very simple date->diff function call but sometimes it will return 1 and other times zero, during the same day under the same conditions. This causes an issue to go past due numerous times rather than just once.

Problematic code-section (contained in foreach $issues as $issue loop):

```
$status = false;
$DEBUG = 'issue ID: '.$issue->ID;

$today = new DateTime("now");
$today->setTime(0, 0, 0); //added this line, as suggested by Sascha

$issue_due = date_create_from_format("Y-m-d", $issue->Due_Date);
$diff = $today->diff($issue_due);
$diff = $diff->format('%r%a');//format as days with positive/negative symbol

//if issue due date is before today and status is not past_due
if ($diff < 0
&& $issue->Status != 'past_due')
{        
    $DEBUG.= ', issue status: '.$issue->Status.' to past_due, today: '.$today->format('d-m-Y').', due: '.$issue_due->format('d-m-Y').', diff: '.$diff;
    //update to past due and mail responsible and (optionally) creator (if not the same person, else send creator mail only)
    $status='past_due';
}
//if issue due date is within 5 days of today and status is not due_soon
if($diff <= 5
&& $diff >= 0
&& $issue->Status != 'due_soon')
{
    //update to due soon and mail to responsible person
    $DEBUG.= ', issue status: '.$issue->Status.' to due_soon, today: '.$today->format('d-m-Y').', due: '.$issue_due->format('d-m-Y').', diff: '.$diff;
    $status='due_soon';
}
if($diff > 5
&& $issue->Status != 'open')
{
    $DEBUG.= ', issue status: '.$issue->Status.' to open, today: '.$today->format('d-m-Y').', due: '.$issue_due->format('d-m-Y').', diff: '.$diff;
    $status='open';
}
```

The debug lines come back like this:

issue ID: 4181, issue status: due_soon to past_due, today: 18-08-2020, due: 17-08-2020, diff: -1, time: 18-Aug 04:12

issue ID: 4181, issue status: past_due to due_soon, today: 18-08-2020, due: 17-08-2020, diff: -0, time: 18-Aug 11:22

issue ID: 4181, issue status: due_soon to past_due, today: 18-08-2020, due: 17-08-2020, diff: -1, time: 18-Aug 11:22

issue ID: 4181, issue status: past_due to due_soon, today: 18-08-2020, due: 17-08-2020, diff: -0, time: 18-Aug 11:31

issue ID: 4181, issue status: due_soon to past_due, today: 18-08-2020, due: 17-08-2020, diff: -1, time: 18-Aug 11:33

This doesn't happen every time somebody accesses the site, although the code is fired with every page access. It can happen a different amount of times for different issues due on the same day. Nothing makes sense anymore, am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 0):

You create a date for now but this is not only a date it has time too and your comparing-date has this too. So it depends on the time of both of them if the result is 0 or 1.
You could set on both date for comparing purpose the same time (hours, minutes, seconds and milliseconds. Other way is to get from both days year, month and days and creating out of this a new date, so both has the same time. If you need daydifference set the time better to 12 , so you couldn't get problems with timechange for summer/wintertime.

Comment: I understand your point but if you look at my debug lines, the same code fires twice (or more times depending on page accesses) in the same minute (look at time value at the end of the line) so to my understanding the time shouldnt make a difference in this case?

Comment: Ok, I didn't see this. Than this is not the problem you are searching for but it could probably another problem depending on the business processes